# Should Typing.Optional be used if the default value of the parameter is not None?

Tags: python, typing, mypy

So I know the standard use case of Typing.Optional, which means it is a union between the type and None. E.g.

```
def my_func(a, b=None):
  # type: (str, Typing.Optional[str]) -> str
  # do stuff with the strings
```

But what if the default value for B is an actual string?

```
def my_func(a, b='hello'):
```

Should the type of b be Optional[str] or just str? Because it is optional from the perspective of the user because you aren't required to pass a value when calling this function, but that doesn't mean None should work though. Mypy doesn't seem to detect a problem with either one.

Comment: `Optional` doesn't mean optional. `Union[Whatever, None]` is not "the standard use case" of `typing.Optional`; it is **what `Optional` means**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An argument having the type `Optional[...]` is not about whether the user has to specify it or not, but rather whether the function must account for the argument being potentially `None`. Given this example:

```
def my_func(a, b='hello'):
   pass
```

`b` will be inferred as `str` because `b`, even if not provided by the caller, will have a non-`None` value. As such, attempting to override the default with `None` like this:

```
my_func(..., None)
```

would result in a MyPy error.

Note that I didn't say that `b` can't be explicitly annotated as `Optional[str]`. This is fine:

```
def my_func(a, b: Optional[str] = 'hello'):
   pass
```

`b` can be annotated as `Optional[str]` here because `b`'s default is `str`, and `Optional[str]` is a superset of `str`. Like you pinpointed, `Optional[str]` is `str` union `None`.

This enables the caller to explicitly pass `None` like this:

```
my_func(..., None)
```

Comment: Thanks. Super helpful.